# Solving conditional probability without formula

Tags: probability

How can you solve conditional probability without formula - simply by logic and intuition?

For example, this problem has been circulated here and we all know the formal way to do it. Could anyone show how to logically solve it?

At a workplace 1% of the staff where injured during a year. 60% of all injured where men. 30% of the employees were women. Is it male or female employees that has the biggest risk of getting injured?

Comment: This is too vague.  Do you have a particular problem in mind?

Comment: One technique is to give things particular numbers.  In your example, suppose that there are 1000 employees total, 10 people got injured.  That gives a total of 6 injured men and 4 injured women out of 700 men total and 300 women total.

Comment: I don´t think that we can make **statistically significant** statements. One necessary information is the number of workers.

Comment: @user585380  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Women make up $30\%$ of the workforce, but sustain $40\%$ of the injuries.  So women get injured at a higher rate.

Answer (score 0):

Let consider a staff of $10\,000$ people, $3\,000$ women and $7\,000$ men.

In a year we have $100$ injuried people $60$ men and $40$ women then

- risk for women $\frac{40}{3000}=\frac43 \% >1 \%$
- risk for men $\frac{60}{7000}=\frac67 \%<1 \%$